# htaccess: three variables and two different pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently trying to figure out how to create an htaccess file that will allow me to perform the following, however I have searched everywhere, and on stackoverflow but I cannot find a solution.

I have an existing site, with a directory /brands/, and an htaccess file setup so that putting anything after brands e.g. /brands/diesel redirects to /brands/index.php?brand=diesel.  What I now need to do is redirect anything further in the URL to a seperate page ( in the same directory ), for example /brands/diesel/jeans/male will redirect to inner.php?sear=diesel&t=jeans&g=male

I have tried the following with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ inner.php?sear=$1&t=$2&g=$3 [L]
```

Anyone who is competent at writing htaccess files will probably be able to spot what is wrong immediately, but unfortunately I am not great with these.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add 3 rules. Not just 1. This is rule for `/brands/diesel/jeans`. Not for `/brands/diesel` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to setup RewriteBase.

```
RewriteBase /brands/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ inner.php?sear=$1&t=$2&g=$3 [L]
```

Comment: the htaccess file is already inside the brands folder if that makes any difference?

Comment: In that case, you might have to use RewriteBase.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /brands/

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ inner.php?sear=$1&t=$2&g=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ inner.php?sear=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ inner.php?sear=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This works for two variables, but I cannot get `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ inner.php?sear=$1&t=$2&g=$3 [L,QSA]` to work with three variables unfortunately

Comment: Are you trying to open `/brands/diesel/jeans/male` and getting 404?

Comment: apologies, I have fixed it, i had a trailing slash! The only problem I now have is that the variables are being added on to the end of the URL, they aren't being hidden.

Comment: That is not due to these rules since I am not using R flag. If you post your existing rules I can check and suggest a fix.

Comment: here you go 

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/brands/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Make sure this 301 rule is before my suggested rules and you test in a new browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48628/discussion-between-larrysanchez-and-anubhava)